# Merge Queues in Java

Tags: java, queue

I was wondering whats the best way to write a method to merge an ArrayQueue with another Queue without removing any elements from the q thats passed.

```
eg. queue1 = [1,2,3,4] and queue2 = [5,6,7,8,9,10].
```

When `queue1.mergeQs(queue2)` was called it would create `queue1 = [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8,9,10]` whilst `queue2` would remain `[5,6,7,8,9,10]`

```
    public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q){}
```

This way seems harder to implement than if you were to pass both Queues and return a new merged Queue. Thanks.

Just to clarify, i'm looking for a method to interleave the elements from the two queues.

Comment: Something of note: there is no `ArrayQueue` class in Java. There is `ArrayDeque` and `ArrayBlockingQueue`, though - did you mean one of theses?

Comment: I have created my own ArrayQueue class that implements my own Queue class. The ArrayQmerge class extends the ArrayQueue Class.

Comment: that does make it a little harder for anybody to answer your question. Since you alone can see `ArrayQueue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One detail that might help you is that private fields *are* visible between different object of *the same* class in Java. That means that as long as you only intend to merge queues of your own class, your code has full access to all internal fields, such as the array you use to store your elements.

For the simplest case, where all elements are stored in a linear array with the queue head being at index zero, something like this might be a start:

```
public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q) {
    Object[] array = new Object[this.size() + q.size()];

    int i;
    int o;

    // Interleave elements
    for (i = 0, o = 0; i < this.size() && i < q.size(); ++i) {
        array[o++] = this.array[i];
        array[o++] = q.array[i];
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements
    while (i < this.size()) {
        array[o++] = this.array[i++];
    }

    while (i < q.size()) {
        array[o++] = q.array[i++];
    }

    this.array = array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Queue locally in the merge method, then assign your class's queue to the local version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using  your own homebrew `ArrayQueue` then this is conjecture.

Creating a new queue and returning is as I think you already say is way easier, and more efficient, as inserting elements into an Array backed structure will involve shuffling the rest of the elements down one position for each insert op.

An alternative is to implement `public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q)` by swapping out the underlying array you have backing it. So you get the same easy implementation as returning a new Queue but with the same in place side effect.